# Authentication Info to Backend Service

Tags: rest, wso2-api-manager, adfs2.0, wso2-identity-server

I have a situation, wherein, I have integrated, WSO2APIM, Identity Server, Microsoft ADFS2.0. Configured successfully so that MSADFS is acting as IdP, APIM acting as SP (with /publisher) as a service. Configuration worked fine when accessed(/publisher of APIM), ADFS presented LogonPage, all necessary SAML2.0 exchanges happened perfect and final page (/publisher) presented.
Now, the actual situation is, instead of accessing APIM service (/publisher), I need to access a POST Rest URL(Eg. APIMIP:Port/vendors/payments). This API is configured to hit backend API (Eg. BEIP:Port/vendors/payments). 
1. In above situation, I need to pass the SAML authentication information or any other authorized info to actual BE, somehow.
2. How to achieve it.

Comment: Can you provide more details about the API you are trying to access? Is this something published in API Manager and some application has subscribed to it?

Comment: Yes, the API is published and a Java web application has subscribed it. I found a link that I felt relevant to my question. Please validate whether that link is correct.  https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM180/Passing+Enduser+Attributes+to+the+Backend+Using+JWT

Comment: Chamila, any info on that, please.

Comment: APIs published in apimanager are secured using oauth. Once authorization is done using oauth ,apimanager can send end user(authorized user) detail using JWT to backend as described in [1].But what is the use case where SAML authentication related to api call ?

[1].https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM180/Passing+Enduser+Attributes+to+the+Backend+Using+JWT

Comment: I have a situation wherein, the APIs can be called by many application used inturn by many users. These users are registered in organization's LDAP viz., MSActive Directory. The API Manager is integrated with Identity Server and Identity Server is integrated with MS ADFS. Now, the end user application once accessed, will be directed to ADFS directly. Once authenticated, will be routed back to Service Provider (API M), which inturn sends call to Backend. Here in the backend, I want to access the MSADFS information. Can we achieve it.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38250035/push-user-saml-attributes-to-backend-service-via-wso2-api-manager

Comment: Jenananthan, I am achieving it using the Http Headers now. However, as you have seen in other posts, I am having trouble accepting the http headers at API M, due to exception "Headers too large".