# Push user SAML attributes to backend service via WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using `WSO2 API Gateway` to service API calls. The backend requires custom user attributes `(username, e-mail, etc.)` to be sent as part of the query string in the URL.
 The values for the query string pairs will be provided in the SAML2 token embedded in the API call.

How can a mediator access these custom SAML2 attributes?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom mediator or custom handler to parse the saml token and set it to a header or something . see [Writing Custom+Handlers](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Writing+Custom+Handlers) for sample handler which reads a header .